# is there any way to have a permanent refund contract for ERC20 tokens?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, gas-refund

Im a newbie when it comes to Ethereum but from what I gather, there is a type of crowdsale where if the goal is not met, the investors can send back their tokens and get a refund. However, this is dependent on Goal levels and time limits.

Is there any way that I can create a permanent refund contract for investors? Where at any time, they can send back any amount of tokens up to the amount they purchased, for a refund of that ethereum. I plan on keeping all of the ethereum from investors specificaly set aside for refunds for them, at least for an extended time period of a year or more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can,  The function permits anybody to withdraw the funds they have contributed if and only if You will permit in inside the function `function safeWithdrawal()` . I hope this help.